# Selecting entity with embedded in JPA

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have a Person entity and an embedded address:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    @Embedded
    private Address address;
}
@Embeddable
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Adress {
    private String city;
}
```

When I select my persons using JPQL :

```
Query q = em.createQuery("FROM Person");
```

I do not get the addresses (as JSON string from my REST api)

I've tried :

```
Query q = em.createQuery("FROM Person p JOIN FETCH p.address");
```

But no way !

Comment: JPQL cannot start with "FROM". "SELECT p FROM Person p" would be a minimum. Any decent JPA docs would tell you that. Are you asking a question here also? "But no way" doesn't mean much without telling people what happens ...

Comment: "FROM Person" is working pretty fine. The pb is when I point my browser on the REST  uri to get my persons entities I do not see the addresses.

Comment: That's not what I said. Go and read up on JPQL and you will see that it is NOT valid JPQL, and will not work in other JPA implementations. If you want to tag this question as Hibernate INSTEAD OF JPA/JPQL then fine you can do that, but when you tag the question such it is WRONG.

Comment: Ah, now I understang. thanks